# Diferencia entre id_name y R.id.id_name

Tags: java, android

Estoy empezando con android y me gustaría entender esta diferencia.

Observo que si tengo una "view" creada de nombre id_name, si inspecciono id_name veo que éste es un valor de tipo int.

Sin embargo, si quiero usar el `findViewById()`, el formato dice que debo usar: `findViewById(R.id.id_name)`. Entiendo que R es la clase que almacena los Resources, pero haciendo debug noté que por supuesto `"R.id.id_name"` es también un valor int (tipo requerido por `findViewById()`) y este valor es exactamente igual al valor de `id_name`.

Entonces:

> ¿por qué debo usar: `findViewById(R.id.id_name)` y no sólo
>   `findViewById(id_name)`?

Answer (score 0):

Pues porque ese id esta almacenado en la variable R, aunque los dos sean lo mismo, el id_name simplemente te esta diciendo que es de tipo entero pero esta almacenado en la variable R.

Tienes que usar R.id_name para acceder e el igual que con otros elementos R.string. etc. Ya que todas esos valores clave se encuentran almacenados y clasificados en R.

Comment: Se que sólo debería tomarme esa pildora sin saber lo que hace ya que ese es el formato. Pero igual me intriga. Si en mi código uso `findViewById(id_name)` en vez de `findViewById(R.id.id_name)`, el programa hace exactamento lo mismo. En todo caso, gracias por tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que mencionas de que puedes utilizar el `id_nombre` directamente es porque estas haciendo un `import static` de la propiedad:

```
import static nombreProjecto.R.id.id_nombre;
```

Si vas a las declaraciones de los paquetes veras la definicion del import. En realidad es lo mismo que utilizar `R.id.id_nombre`, solo que con el import static no tendrias que utilizar la referencia completa del campo `id_nombre`. Si deseas hacerlo con otra propiedad tendras que agregar el import en la declaración de los paquetes.

Tambien hay 2 formas de lograrlo ademas del `import static`:

1.

Asignandole el valor del `R.id.id_name` a una variable y sera valido para el analizador:

```
int id_name = R.id.id_name;
TextView nombre = (TextView)findViewById(id_name);
```

2.

Deshabilitar la inspecion de android studio para que te permita ingresar un id cualquiera precionando `ctrl+enter` sobre el error -> Inspection 'Constant and Resource Type Mismatches' options -> Disable inspection:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aunque no es recomendable porque tendrías que aprenderte el id del elemento que es un integer.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Tengo el **_Android Studio_** instalado hace una semana y no he cambiado ninguna de sus opciones por defecto así que dudo que tenga deshabilitada la opción del punto 2. En cuanto al punto 1, yo no creé la constante (final int) con ese nombre y, aún así, si ejecuto en el código `findViewById(id_name)` en vez de `findViewById(R.id.id_name)`, el programa hace exactamento lo mismo. Lo que estoy tratando es de saber por qué debo usar la clase R y no el id directamente. Debe existir una razón y creo que me ayudaría mucho saberla para entender correctamente lo que sucede. Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Mira la respuesta actualizada por favor.

Comment: Quizá aquí consigas mi error. `package com.example.ejercicio1;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...
    private void dispPrice(int number) {
        TextView priceTextView = (TextView)   findViewById(R.id.price);
        // TextView priceTextView = (TextView) findViewById(price); // Hace lo mismo. Why?
priceTextView.setText(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(number));
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

La referencia de la vista `id_name` se almacena como tipo `Int`, ya que al compilar tu programa se genera una entrada en el archivo `R.java` que hace referencia a este recurso.

Por ejemplo si creamos una vista:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/id_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

dentro del archivo `R.java` que almacena referencias de los recursos de tu aplicación, será generada una entrada dentro de la clase `id` :

```
public static final class id {
     ...
     public static final int id_name=0x7f0f0096;
     ...
```

Por lo tanto tienes que agregar `R.id` para poder acceder directamente a la referencia del elemento, de otra forma no podrás acceder a esta; Clase `R` donde se encuentran registrados los recursos de tu aplicación, Clase `id`, variable `id_name`

```
findViewById(R.id.id_name)
```

---

Dentro del archivo `R.java` también se tienen otro tipo de clases que también definen el tipo de elementos que contienen, como son:

```
    public static final class drawable {
          ...
          ...

   public static final class id {
          ...
          ...

   public static final class dimen {
          ...
          ...

   public static final class color {
          ...
          ...

  public static final class anim {
         ...
         ...
 public static final class array {
         ...
         ...
```

> ¿por qué debo usar: findViewById(R.id.id_name) y no sólo
>   findViewById(id_name)?

Para acceder a los elementos dentro de estas clases es importante agregar la clase en la cual se encuentran, en este caso `id_name` se encuentra dentro de la clase `id`.